# Draw lines in jpanel using jslider value

Tags: java, swing, components, jslider

I want to divide a jpanel equally by drawing lines, so when i drag the jslider to 2 then i want my jpanel to be divided by 2 , and so on.Like the page [http://illuminations.nctm.org/Activity.aspx?id=3510][1]
Below is my code

```
 MyDrawPanel panel;
JFrame frame;
int x = 0;
int counter = 0;
int stepping = 0;
JSlider hslider;
public static void main(String[] args){
    DividePanel div = new DividePanel();
    div.go();
}

public void go(){

    frame = new JFrame("My Frame");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    hslider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL,1,4,4);
    //hslider.setValue(1);
    hslider.setMajorTickSpacing(1);
    hslider.setPaintLabels(true);
    hslider.setPaintTicks(true);
    hslider.addChangeListener(new HsliderListener());

    panel = new MyDrawPanel();
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE,2,false));

    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH,hslider);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER,panel); 

    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

public class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel{

    public MyDrawPanel(){
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));
    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
     //g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
     //g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());

     for(int i=1; i<counter; i+=100){
        stepping=400/counter;
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.drawLine(0, x+stepping, this.getWidth(), i+stepping);
     }

    }
}
  public class HsliderListener implements ChangeListener{

    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        counter = hslider.getValue();

        panel.repaint();
    }

}
```

If anyone can help i would be thankful.
Sorry for the bad english.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"I have a problem with the jslider which i want to divide a jpanel equally when i drag it"*  Sounds like a job better suited to a `JSplitPane`..  BTW - For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).

Comment: super.paintComponent ......